# Drop To Frame sometimes disabled, sometimes not

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I often use the Eclipse Debgugging function **Drop To Frame**, but sometimes it is not available when debugging. I found [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472562/drop-to-frame-feature-disabled-in-eclipse-debug-while-running-testcases-using-ju) and an [Eclipse Help entry](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-droptoframe.htm), which says:

> Note this command is only available if the current VM supports drop to frame and the selected stackframe is not the top frame or a frame in a native method.

My problem is, while debugging the same function (its not the top stack frame, and neither it or its parent is a native method - though there is one 3 levels higher) I sometimes find that Drop to Frame is enabled and I sometimes find it is disabled.

Do you know any more limitations to Drop To Frame, which could be a reason for it not being available? Note: I use the same JVM all the time, and I can't quite imagine it sometimes supports Drop To Frame and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has the same problem: Since we switched from an earlier Eclipse Version (I think Luna) to Neon, the problem doesn't occur anymore. Maybe it was a bug that was fixed in newer Eclipse versions and only occured from time to time.